# Custom Post Type and Functions

Tags: plugin-development, customization

There is a very poor coding practice among freelancers that they create individual pages for every custom post types, but I think there is a better way to do this by Creating functions in `functions.php` and then calling those functions.

For any Function/meta created in `functions.php`, how to integrate or call that function for Custom Post types?

I am unable to Understand the basic logic can come one explain.

### EDIT from comments

> ....my question was suppose there is a meta created for BIG text (Through Function)and now we have 10 custom post types and we want this meta to be shown in 5 CPT's then w/o repeating the codes how can we build function and attach it to those custom post types?

Comment: Your question does not really make sense.

Comment: Also, custom post types  **should be** registered in a plugin, and not in a theme

Comment: I Know that CPT should be registered in plugin, but my question was suppose there is a meta created for BIG text (Through Function)and now we have 10 custom post types and we want this meta to be shown in 5 CPT's then w/o repeating the codes how can we build function and attach it to those custom post types?

Comment: Different templates for different post types is perfectly normal and encouraged. Parsing and processing one 500-liner template is much more efficient than parsing very huge functions.php **+** CPT should be added _via_ plugin which means that if you disable the plugin, template doesn't eat resources for no reason but if you have everything in functions.php, it will still have to parse it. None of the files _(not even functions.php)_ should be huge.

Comment: Are you talking about custom post type archives or single custom post type posts

Comment: Maybe it would be best to show an example of what meta you are talking about. I don't think anyone knows what BIG text is except you -- let alone what meta you need to reuse.